# Routing optional parameters in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC 5 application and I have some issues with routing. We are using the attribute `Route` to map our routes in the web application. I have the following action:

```
[Route("{type}/{library}/{version}/{file?}/{renew?}")]
public ActionResult Index(EFileType type, 
                          string library, 
                          string version, 
                          string file = null, 
                          ECacheType renew = ECacheType.cache)
{
 // code...
}
```

We only can access this URL if we pass the slash char `/` in the end of `url`, like this:

```
type/lib/version/file/cache/
```

It works fine but does not work without `/`, I get a `404` not found error, like this

```
type/lib/version/file/cache
```

or this (without optional parameters):

```
type/lib/version
```

I would like to access with or without `/` char at the end of `url`. My two last parameters are optional.

My `RouteConfig.cs` is like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

How can I solve it? Make the slash `/` be optional too?

Comment: By "does not work" you mean you get 404 Not Found?

Comment: Yes! 404 error, if I add a breakpoint, it just does not hit on the breakpoint!

Comment: Does the application hosted as a Virtual Directory?

Comment: Starting from Visual Studio, it's running on the IIS Express!

Comment: IIS Express with Virtual Directory or installed on root?

Comment: I believe it's a virtual directory!

Comment: Can you show your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Comment: If `{file}` is not provided, but `{renew}` is, how is it supposed to know which one you provided since they are both optional?

Comment: All optional parameters are processed in order so `{file}` always has to be given if `{renew}` is there. I tried you code above and it worked just fine for me. I tried both with tailing `/` and without...had the same result. I tried both with and without the optional parameters...same successful result. How have you defined your enums? Are they defined with set integer values?

Comment: @Ohlin, my enum I pass as string, with the same name of each item. How is your `RouteConfig.cs`?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Maybe you should try to have your enums as integers instead?

This is how I did it

```
public enum ECacheType
{
    cache=1, none=2
}

public enum EFileType 
{
    t1=1, t2=2
}

public class TestController
{
    [Route("{type}/{library}/{version}/{file?}/{renew?}")]
    public ActionResult Index2(EFileType type,
                              string library,
                              string version,
                              string file = null,
                              ECacheType renew = ECacheType.cache)
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
}
```

And my routing file

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    // To enable route attribute in controllers
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
}
```

I can then make calls like

```
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1/file1/1
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1/file1
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1
```

or

```
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1/file1/1/
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1/file1/
http://localhost:52392/2/lib1/ver1/
```

and it works fine...

Answer (score -8):

```
//its working with mvc5
[Route("Projects/{Id}/{Title}")]
public ActionResult Index(long Id, string Title)
{
    return view();
}
```