# How to add a dummy class as parameter in a controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

My controller contains

```
 [Route("/sales")]
 public IActionResult Index()
 {
     Model myModel = new Model();
     return test(DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today, myModel);
 }
```

and the test method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("/sales/{startDate}/{endDate}/{myModel}")]
public IActionResult test(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Model myModel = null)
{
    myModel ??= new Model();
    return View(myModel);
}
```

On page load everything works as expected. Index method, passes the model to the test function.

Unfortunatelly when an AJAX post occures at

```
/sales/2020-05-14/2020-05-14/null
```

i get an internal server error (500), which seems to be logical.

But how can i fix that? Is there any attribute that i can decorate the optional parameter `Model myModel = null`

Actually i want to treat this property as dummy when called from client side, 
and that is why i have set it to null.

Comment: and what is the excpetion you get when you get the 500 error?

Comment: Optional parameter can use in this way, see the another SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24678045/routing-optional-parameters-in-asp-net-mvc-5 for detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MSDN:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#optional-arguments)

> The definition of a method, constructor, indexer, or delegate can
>   specify that its parameters are required or that they are optional.
>   Any call must provide arguments for all required parameters, but can
>   omit arguments for optional parameters.

As your `myModel` argument is optional, you can omit it from ajax call. *To omit this argument you need to make this parameter as an optional in route as well,*

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("/sales/{startDate}/{endDate}/{myModel?}")]
public IActionResult test(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, Model myModel = null)
{
    myModel ??= new Model();
    return View(myModel);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To mark the route parameter as optional use the "?". So it will look like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [Route("/sales/{startDate}/{endDate}/{myModel?}")]
    public IActionResult test([FromRoute] DateTime startDate, [FromRoute] DateTime endDate, [FromRoute] Model myModel = null)
    {
        myModel ??= new Model();
        return View(myModel);
    }
```